# Custom DataAnnotationsModelValidator for CompareAttribute does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

In my ASP.NET project, I created a custom DataAnnotationsModelValidator for the CompareAttribute.
(The one in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace, not the obsolete one.)

The reason is that I want to add some custom logic to replace the error message, but actually the problem arises even before I add this custom logic.

```
public class LocalizableCompareAnnotationsAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<CompareAttribute>
{
    public LocalizableCompareAnnotationsAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, CompareAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
    }
}

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(CompareAttribute), typeof(LocalizableCompareAnnotationsAdapter));
```

As you can see, I'm doing nothing special yet... Just creating this custom adapter. The problem is that this seems to break my validation, so wherever I'm using a CompareAttribute, it stops working (at least client-side).

Does anyone know why this breaks validation? The project contains similar custom adapters for other validation attributes such as RequiredAttribute and RegularExpressionAttribute. These work fine without problems.

Comment: Have just tested this, and when you use the `[Compare]` attribute, no `data-val-*` attributes are created, but if you override the `GetClientValidationRules()` method in your `LocalizableCompareAnnotationsAdapter`, then the `data-val-*` attributes are added (but the ones from your attribute, not the `CompareAttribute`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the feedback. Maybe overriding GetClientValidationRules would be a step in the right direction, but I don't understand why the default behavior of the CompareAttribute is broken at all. (Edit: before adding this custom adapter, the data-val-* attributes were added correctly.)

Comment: Not sure either. When I get a chance I'll do some debugging to see why.

Comment: You have claimed that you have done the same for a `RequiredAttribute`, and that it works, but it does not. Again the `data-val-*` attributes are not generated and client side validation cannot work (unless you override the `GetClientValidationRules()` method to add the rules.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidator(v=vs.118).aspx) 'Remarks' section, its not clear but it suggests that when you create a `DataAnnotationsModelValidator` and register it, it becomes the 'Default', and that you need to override `GetClientValidationRules()` to generate the rules for client side validation.

Comment: Its not really clear what the purpose of this attribute is, but the fact you have named it `Localizable....` suggests your wanting to display different messages based on a culture, in which case why not use Resource files?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Strange that it seems to work with the RequiredAttribute in our project. Probably something else hooks into it somewhere, fixing it... Anyway, I've managed to get it working by overriding GetClientValidationRules for the CompareAttribute. Thanks for the help!

Comment: By the way, the reason that we're not using Resource files is that the translations are fetched from a CMS (Sitecore) with some custom logic. Otherwise, good suggestion.